# Idempotence of Fremlin essential interior and closure operators

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory, idempotents

Fremlin's book "Measure theory" 475B defines two monotone operators on the whole power set of $R^n$ denoted essential interior and essential closure:

\begin{eqnarray}
X \mapsto int^* X:=\lbrace x\in R^n \quad |  \quad \liminf_{\delta \downarrow 0} \frac{\mu_*(B(x,\delta) \cap X)}{\mu(B(x,\delta))} =1 \rbrace \\
X \mapsto cl^* X :=\lbrace x\in R^n \quad |  \quad \limsup_{\delta \downarrow 0} \frac{\mu^*(B(x,\delta) \cap X)}{\mu(B(x,\delta))} >0 \rbrace
\end{eqnarray}
where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure and $\mu^*$, $\mu_*$ are the induced outer and inner measures. He then shows that $int^*$ preserves intersections and $cl^*$ preserves unions.

I would like to know *under what conditions they can be showed to be idempotent*. For sure they are idempotent for measurable sets for which upper and lower densities agree, but I would like to know if it is possible to prove idempotence for arbitrary sets.

Comment: I have the following naive idea, which I have not checked yet. Given a set $X\subset\Bbb R^n$, take measurable subsets $X_*\subset X\subset X^*$ such that for each cube $C_v=[0,1]^n+v$, where $v\in\Bbb Z^n$ we have $\mu(X_*\cap C_v)=\mu_*(X\cap C_v) $ and $\mu^*(X^*\cap C_v)=\mu^*(X\cap C_v) $. Maybe then $int^*X= int^*X_*$ and $cl_*X= cl^*X^*$, so these operators are idempotent?